# Replace consecutive numbers by first numbers in a string with Regex/PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have that string : `$text=70ac0f2e7247e9a658f71fe6362bf53`

I want to replace all consecutive numbers by only the first number. For example I want to replace **70** by 7, **7247** by 7, **658** by 6 and so on.

I have this pattern : `$pattern = '/[0-9]{2,}/';` but I don't know how I could build the `$replacement` and the *preg_replace* to make :

```
preg_replace ($pattern2,$replacement,$text3);
```

Thank you !

Comment: Try `preg_replace('/(\d)\d*/', "$1", $text3);`

Comment: or even `\d\K\d*`

Comment: Great thank you @revo !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer, you need to use a capturing group:

```
preg_replace('/([0-9])[0-9]*/', '$1', $text3);
```

or like what @chris85 said you may go with a match resetter `\K`:

```
preg_replace('/[0-9]\K[0-9]*/', '', $text3);
```